# Setting up Github with an used Macbook

Tags: github

I recently used my wife's MacBook (I have a desktop in my office, but since the university is closed, I am not allowed to go there.) This Macbook was used to set up AWS before. In particular, some ssh keys were created.

Recently, I am trying to set up Github. All the guidelines on the internet seem to suggest that we have to start from the beginning. As a consequence, I am having a hard time setting up Github.

I am a completely new user of Macbook. I wonder whether it is possible to reset everything on my wife's Macbook so that I can set up my Github connection?

I am sorry if my question is too silly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Offtopic here, but [does this help](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I read and followed that link before posting my question. However, it got some errors-which I believe due to the fact that some ssh keys already existed on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You should first install git using one of [the following methods](https://git-scm.com/download/mac). Then you can use command line arguments to [clone a desired repository](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/cloning-a-repository) or perform whatever action you need. If you are not comfortable using the command line to manage your project with git, then you can install [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) to obtain a convenient UI for managing the project.

Not sure if this is what you meant by "setting up GitHub" but hope it helps. Let me know if there's anything else I can help with.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Github desktop works well for me. I just set up some repo on Github. I will take a look at the other method that you recommended. Cheers, Tung